# Resolve issues Autolayout constraints

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to understand properly the use of Autolayout constraints in Xcode 7 and after trying to learn it with some amazing tutorials, I'm still having a lot of issues. The screen I show below is a simple screen used to redirect the users either to sing up form or sign in:

[image]

After applying Autolayout constraints the undesired result below:

[image]

How you can see the buttons in the bottom have disappeared and the sign up button height is higher than expected.

Finally Im going to show below the constraints configuration:

[image]

Comment: If you understand the minimum requirements for an unambiguous layout and constraints in horizontal/vertical directions. Then you can work with it very easily.
Try this chapter https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1.

Answer (score 0):

You should only add constraints that allow xCode to figure out the x and y position of a view along with height and width.
For example: Sign Up button has a top space to main label. Now the same sign up button has bottom constraints to already registered label which in turn has a FIXED distance from the bottom along with a FIXED height. It doesn't know how to display the view when the screen is different size. It is trying to maintain all the specified constraints on its view which it is unable to do. For starters try removing the fixed distance of sign up button from the main label.

In your console, when loading the view. The debugger should show which constraints are conflicting and which constraints are being removed by XCode.

Answer (score 0):

**I use the following approach when dealing with AutoLayout.**

As a general rule I try to **apply AutoLayout "Top-Down",** however, I need to bear in mind that iPhone 4s is a lot smaller than the iPhone 6+.

**TOP-DOWN approach works well if there is a scroll view behind** it allowing different sizes to scroll down between objects at the top and those at the bottom of the existing screen.

e.g. from your Screen shots...

**"Main" label:**

Align Top/ Left/ Right + Fix height.Then...

**"Sign up" button:**

Again - Align Top/ Left/ Right + Fix height. Etc...

**However, if you are not using Scroll View in the background**, the objects at the bottom will not be visible depending simulator screen size.

**Solution:**
Rather than align lower placed objects to the TOP,

Align them (lower objects) to the bottom and fix their heights.

i.e. Dual effect 'Top-Down'+ 'Bottom-Up'

e.g.

**"Sign in" Button:**

Align Bottom/ Right + Fix Height & Width.

**"Already register" label:**

Align Bottom/ Right + Fix Height & Width.

**"Sign Up" Button:**

Align Bottom/ Left/ Right + Fix Height.

**In summary:**

*1. If Scroll View is available in background the approach of aligning items to TOP (with Top-Down approach) can be used.*

*2. Otherwise, a dual approach of 'Top-Down' + 'Down-Up' needs to be used bearing in the effect on small + large screens without use of a scroll feature*